# Graphviz absolute positioning with subgroup clusters

Tags: graphviz, dot

```
digraph G {
  splines=false

  node [ pin=true ]

  1 [pos="0,0",label="A"];
  2 [pos="1,0",label="B"];
  3 [pos="2,0",label="C"];
  4 [pos="3,0",label="D"];
  1 -> 2;
  2 -> 3;
  3 -> 4;
}
```

The Graphviz dot script above (ex.dot) produces the following output image:

[image: this image]

I use the `fdp` command for this, with the following invocation: `fdp -Tpng ex.dot -o ex.png`. Each node is aligned horizontally as required; according to the `pos` attribute.

```
digraph G {
  splines=false

  node [ pin=true ]

  subgraph cluster_s1 { 1 2 };
  1 [pos="0,0",label="A"];
  2 [pos="1,0",label="B"];
  3 [pos="2,0",label="C"];
  4 [pos="3,0",label="D"];
  1 -> 2;
  2 -> 3;
  3 -> 4;
}
```

I would like to outline a subgraph. However, if I add `subgraph cluster_s1 { 1 2 }`, as shown in the script above, the output image now has the 4 nodes misaligned, as shown below. How can I fix this? Can I have both fixed positioning and clustering?

[image]

Comment: not on http://viz-js.com/ - what version are you using?

Comment: fdp - graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041) on Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: I tried it via the link you sent, and got the same output as in my question.

Comment: You need to use `fdp`? With `dot` and `rankdir=LR` you would get exactly what you want, for this example at least.

Comment: No, I don't. Thanks - that works for me. I then had a small problem as there actually should be no edge between nodes 3 and 4; but then I just made it invisible: `3 -> 4[style=invis]`

Comment: Note that fdp (and dot) ignore the pos attribute.  neato -n is the only program that uses the pos attribute.